# Importing a Maven Project jar in Eclipse for another Maven Project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, jar

It's one of the first times I use Maven.

I have a create a New Project in Eclipse, that needs classes from a previous Java Project that I have developed.

I exported the old Maven project as a non-executable jar, using the default settings that Eclipse gave me. One of dependencies that the old project has is the jdbc mysql driver.

When I imported the oldProject.jar in the New Maven Project, using some of the old classes, Eclipse raises an error.

Then I added the jdbc mysql driver as a Maven Dependency, but I am still not able to launch anything because:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
java/sql/SQLException
at ---/dummy.dummy_class.main(dummy_class.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
```

Then I tried to move the jar from the Maven folder to another one (lib folder) and manually including it in the build path, but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the old project must have a pom with tags like follows

```
<groupId>com.project</groupId> 
<artifactId>old-project-name</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <!-- mysql as dependency if you want use it in new project -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

and you need add old project as new project dependency

in new project pom:

```
 <dependencies>
        ...
        <!-- old project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>old-project-name</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
       ...
```

in this way new project can use  classes and dependencies from old project like mysql

Comment: Tried to do so, but probably there is some inconsistency between the oldProject.jar name and the filename that the new project's Maven expects. I know that I am probably doing some newbie mistake.

Comment: Installed the local .jar in Maven alongside the pom.xml file as described in https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html with no luck